# How to create profession box shadow effect in div using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]I am creating an application where i am using divs to show information and and using some jQuery to manipulate them.In my application i  want to give box shadow to my div and trying to make a professional look.I have created box shadow to my div but it does not look that professional.I am using this link to prepare my application.
 [Refence UI](http://www.headhonchos.com/js_profiles?ref=nav_profile)

Now i want to create my personal information div exactly same as the Summary div in that application. I am also posting my code what i have done so far in a fiddle

```
#personalInformation{
    font-size: 1em;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #98AFC7;
    border-top: 3px solid #98AFC7;
    border-left: 3px solid #98AFC7;
    border-right: 3px solid #98AFC7;    
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px;
    line-height: 0; 
    width: 45%;
}
```

[My sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/muq10yh3/)

Now can anyone help me to make my div exactly same as that application ?? or if not possible then how to make the box shadow in bottom only?? Somebody please help .

Comment: I modify your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/muq10yh3/1/

Comment: I've updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cL7zwvzt/

Comment: Thanks for answering but can you help me to make the back ground like that application ??

Comment: Can you please clear what exactly do you need :) exact same info box like that application?

Comment: yes yes exact same info box i want

Comment: @UsmanArshad can you help me to change the background color like that application

Comment: @lucifer check my answer below, also created code snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80287/discussion-between-lucifer-and-usman-arshad).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created exactly same box with background like that application. Hope it may help you.

```css
html {
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    body {
      font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
      font-size: 100%;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.42857143;
      background-color: #f4f4f4;
      color: #404040;
    }

    .content {
      float: left;
      width: 870px;
    }
      .content::after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: table;
      }

    .box {
      padding: 5px 15px;
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #c9c9c9;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #c9c9c9;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #c9c9c9;
      border-radius: 2px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .box:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #bababa;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #bababa;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #bababa;
    }
      .box h5 {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        line-height: 1.1;
      }
      .box p {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.5;
        margin: 0 0 10px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div id="your-id" class="box">
    <div class="box-content">
      <h5>Caption</h5>
      <p id="your-id">Not Mentioned</p>
      <h5>Skills/Competencies</h5>
      <p id="your-id">Layout  ,CSS  ,JavaScript  ,jQuery  ,HTML5  ,WordPress  ,Web Design  ,Web Development  ,HTML  ,PHP  ,AJAX  ,Cross-browser Compatibility  ,CSS3  ,UI/UX  ,Expert Frontend Developer  ,Responsive Web Design  ,Website Development  ,Web 2.0  ,Dreamweaver  ,Web Applications  ,Image Manipulation  ,Drupal  ,MySQL  ,Web Application Design  ,Web Interface Design  ,SVG  ,Front-end Development            </p>
      <h5>Resumes</h5>
      <p id="your-id">not mentioned</p>
    </div>
  </div><!-- .box -->
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Usman let me implement this to my UI and i will accept your answer please bear with me for the time being ,and thanks a lot bro

Comment: and can i use id instead of your class ??because i have some jQuery function which calls the id

Comment: Let classes as they are and add your id regarding your jQuery function, it will doesn't effect to UI. You welcome bro.

Comment: Means what you r saying i will not change the id to your classes ?? on top of the ids i will put your classes ??? If you once edit my fiddle then it will be more clear

Comment: @lucifer I updated the snippet, add your on "your-id".

Answer (score 0):

I have provided an example here using HAML and SCSS. Please hit the compiled button to retrieve the rendered content. Its a very simple illusion. The background shadow is a soft black color. Let me know if you any more questions

HAML:

```
#my-box Hello World!
```

SCSS:

```
$background: #3D6CAD;
$soft-black-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.29);

html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: $background; }

#my-box {
  float: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 1px $soft-black-shadow;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Stephn_R/pen/pJwdzB

And the edits applied to your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muq10yh3/4/)

Comment: can you edit my fiddle ? then it will be very help full to me ??

Comment: Added! Check it out :)

Comment: where i should add those $background: #3D6CAD;
$soft-black-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.29); it is not in the fiddle

Comment: Yes I changed the fiddle. Only the background shadow needed to be updated. The SCSS variables are just pointing to colors you would wish to use for the page background and the shadow background